# libc++'s implementation of std::map/set::equal_range gives unexpected results

Tags: c++, libc++

I noticed `std::set::equal_range` (same for `std::map`) in clang's libc++ gives different result than libstdc++.
I always assumed `equal_range` should return equivalent of `std::make_pair(set.lower_bound(key), set.upper_bound(key))` which is what cppreference says and libstdc++ does.
In libc++ however I have a code which gives a different result.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct comparator {
    using range_t = std::pair<int, int>;
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;
    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(int lhs, range_t rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs.first;
    }
    bool operator()(range_t lhs, int rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.second < rhs;
    }
};

using range_set = std::set<int, comparator>;

int main()
{
    range_set set = { 1, 3, 6, 10 };
    auto range = comparator::range_t{2, 7};
    auto eq = set.equal_range(range);
    auto low = set.lower_bound(range);
    auto high = set.upper_bound(range);
    std::cout << "equal_range returned " << std::distance(eq.first, eq.second) << " elem(s): ";
    std::copy(eq.first, eq.second, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\nlower/upper returned " << std::distance(low, high) << " elem(s): ";
    std::copy(low, high, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see at https://rextester.com/CLTS82056 this gives

```
equal_range returned 1 elem(s): 3 
lower/upper returned 2 elem(s): 3 6
```

With `libstdc++` as well as with `boost::container::set` I get 2 elements (which I expect) in both cases.

Of course I can manually call `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` in my code but using `equal_range` is shorter, clearly shows my intention (I want to find all elements which fall into the given range) and might be faster (because `equal_range` method could be coded as one tree traversal without actual calls to `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`).

Interestingly enough, changing container type to `std::multiset` in this case makes `equal_range` return 2 elements.

Now is this a bug in `libc++` or does cppreference give wrong hint in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range:

> Alternatively, the first iterator may be obtained with `lower_bound()`, and the second with `upper_bound()`.

Comment: It looks to me like the effective result your range comparator's strict weak ordering is implemented in a way that results in 3 and 6 in the `std::set` compare equal to the range value that gets passed in to `equal_range`. Given that `std::set` is supposed to contain unique values only, the libc implementation might be assuming that once it finds a value that compares equal, that's all the set has. I find nothing in a brief review of what N4659 says that supports this. The only thing I see is that `comparator` should define `is_transparent`. Not sure, but I'll point the finger at libc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine.

You are testing on an outdated libc++. This is [bug 30959](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30959), fixed in 2018 and available in clang 7.

Rextester's clang is apparently 3.8.

Comment: Great to hear that, I was using clang 6 on my side and seems it is finally time to upgrade

Comment: Heh, I could've sworn I scribbled down something about partitioning being the only requirement for transparent comparisons, a long time ago. Must've been a figment of my imagination...